# Whatsapp backup restore without SD

Tags: whatsapp

i need to transfer whatsapp messages from lumia 1020 to microsoft lumia 532.i have created backup from inside whatsapp application. but the problem is their is no SD card in 1020. i installed whatsapp in my new phone but there is not any restore option there.what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you're using the **same phone number** (same SIM card) since you can't sync/restore your messages using another account.

According to the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/23607796):

> WhatsApp automatically makes backups of your chat history every day at 4 AM and you can uninstall and reinstall WhatsApp to restore messages from this copy. **If you are unable to restore your chats, unfortunately, we can not restore your chats, contacts or multimedia files for you.**

So, granted that you're using the same phone number the backup/restore should be done automatically. As a matter of fact, this is what happened to me.

Other than, remember that you have the option to export your conversations to .txt format by following the next steps:

```
1. Open the chat you wish to export.
2. Tap More  > info or group info.
3. Tap More  > email chat history.
```

Comment: This method (automatic backup at 4am or manual backup) is not working if you don't have an SD card. The backup is stored at `SDcard->whatsapp->winphonebackup`. If you don't have an SDcard and try the backup, no files are saved in phone memory. The user has tried the backup option in the settings. Read the question carefully. He says "i have created backup from inside whatsapp application" which is exactly what you are suggesting. The problem is restoring a backup without SDcard.

Comment: I agree with Aventinus, please read the questions carefully.
There is no way to restore your chat on your new device if your windows phone has no SD card. I know it is crazy and sad but unfortunately it is the truth. After experiencing this I switched to Telegram, it is a reliable and more secure app and u can install it on as much as devices you want with the same number and no matter when and where you install it you get all the old messages on your new device. Whatsapp sucks people, that is a fact!